# Does Positional Interpolation Change Llama's Architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, llm

I'm currently exploring Meta's positional interpolation method, which aims to increase the context size in their large language model. This method extends the context length from **n x n** into **n′ x n′**. It achieves this by interpolating new token values in between existing ones.

My question: Does this interpolation technique necessitate changes to the underlying model architecture? Specifically, how does the self-attention matrix, configured as an n × n matrix, adapt to accommodate the extended context size of n′ x n′?